# 'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode11.3

I have  ,"pod install ", and my pod file look like this :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
#platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyTaxii' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyTaxii


           pod 'Firebase/Core'
           pod 'Firebase/Database'
           pod 'Firebase/Auth'
           pod  'Firebase/Storage'
           pod 'GeoFire', '>= 1.1'

end
```

i open the .xworkspace and after running i get error

```
"'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found "
```

in my  " GeoFire.m "  "and GFQuery.m"

Comment: Are you trying to connect firebase here ? Or what exactly do you want to achieve here ?

Comment: connecting firebase, i specified those pod in my pod file and ran " pod install" , after that i  opened my .xworkspace and built the project and im facing these errors

Comment: Please confirm if you have added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and completed this step here `https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#initialize-firebase`

Comment: yes i did , im getting these error before i " import Firebase" in my AppDelegate,

Comment: so i tried to" import Firebase "in my AppDelegate.swift and there also im getting an error => No such a module "Firebase"

Answer (score 3):

In addition to trying to clean your cache, try to change "use_frameworks!" for "use_modular_headers!". This is the only solution that worked for me.

```
 target 'iosApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Pods for iosApp
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth'
end
```

Comment: this seems working. all not found issues gone. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem.But fixed.

You just need to **pod update**
pod update means that updating local specs repositories.

when I pod install.
Firebase **version is 6.34.0.**

```
% pod install

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Firebase 2.4.1.1
Installing Firebase 6.34.0 (was 2.4.1.1)
```

**But after pod update**.
Firebase version is  **8.4.0 (was 2.4.1.1)**

```
% pod update

Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies

Installing Firebase 8.4.0 (was 2.4.1.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 8.4.0 (was 6.9.0)
Installing FirebaseAnonymousAuthUI (12.0.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth 8.4.0 (was 6.9.2)
Installing FirebaseAuthUI (12.0.0)
```

Another is no change for me.

Answer (score 1):

solved it by :

' pod update ' ,

Basically you may need to do these steps:

1.open your podfile and comment the pods

2) go to terminal making sure your in your project directory

3)' pod uninstall '

4) open back podfile and insert pods back and  Command Save

5) go to terminal ....' pod install '

6) also do .....pod update after # 5( better to read cocoapod "pod update " if you need specific version , here:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html)

7) open .xworkspace and run

8) command shift k(cleans it)

9) may need to repeat process #1-8

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the pods given and faced the same issue which you have mentioned. To resolve this issue,

you can do `CMD + shift + k` or `product -> clean build folder`.

The  entire project needs to be build again. If you have a lot of pods/frameworks or source code this can take some time to recompile. This resolved the pods issue.

Comment: i have tried it already and still getting same errors, also i tried :                                             pod deintegrate  & pod install          and still getting same errors

Comment: the errors are  :lexical or preprocessor issue :
'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found at GFQuery.m                                                                 
'Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found  at GeoFire.m

Comment: can you provide the steps to reproduce ? I have a deployment target of iOS 13.2. and it works fine with this version . what about yours?

Comment: im using Xcode  11.3.1.  and my deployment target is  iOS 13.2

Comment: have you checked the deployment info under Targets ? is Target 13.2 ? And for Project, deployment target is 13.2 ?

Comment: Deployment:                                           
iOS Deployment Target > iOS 13.2

Comment: Go to General -> TARGETS -> MyTaxii -> Deployment Info -> What is the Target  ? Then, General -> PROJECT -> MyTaxii -> what is the Deployment Target ?

Comment: both are iOS 13.2

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the same deployment target. I have committed the working project here, https://github.com/vinayakasy99/podissue

Answer (score 0):

Could also be a corrupt Xcode module cache. Try quitting Xcode, `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, restarting Xcode, rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me absolutely bananas, but I think I resolved it simply by adding `firebase_analytics: ^10.6.1` to my pubspec. So for me, the full list for getting crashlytics to work in pubspec was:

```
  firebase_analytics: ^10.6.1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.1
  firebase_core: ^2.19.0
```

I then deleted Podfile.lock, `pod install`, and I was past this error. I also needed to clean up redundant packages (from various other attempts), and this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791771/2752129

Onto the next nightmarish configuration errors...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your library was out of the update, please recheck the version Firebase.
Instead of import general `<Firebase/Firebase.h>`, Firebase splited into specific libraries such as `<FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore>`, `<FirebaseAuth/FirebaseAuth.h>`