# Flutter on iOS: redefinition of module 'Firebase'

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, xcodebuild

I've been trying to build my flutter app on iOS but `flutter run` is throwing the following error:

```
/Users/<MyUser>/Desktop/projects/app/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Source
s/module.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'Firebase'
module Firebase {
       ^
/Users/<MyUser>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbkgurnsasbvieahfnk
dontejqss/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/CoreOnly/Sources/module.
modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module Firebase {
```

I've imported the firebase-ios-sdk as per the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup). The imported modules are FirebaseCore, FirebaseAuth and FirebaseMessaging. I have not made any modifications to iOS-specific code (anything under /ios) apart from importing Firebase in the AppDelegate.swift file. The updated file now contains the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
 ) -> Bool {
   FirebaseApp.configure()
   GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
   return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }
}
```

After searching the error I've tried the following steps:

- `flutter clean`
- `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`
- Cleaning DerivedData (both through XCode and manually)
- Remove and re-add firebase-ios-sdk

But to no avail.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this issue by removing the firebase-ios-sdk dependency altogether. It appears that this is imported by the Flutter dependencies and adding it manually thus leads to a redefinition error.

I'd advise any people encountering this or similar errors to make sure that the integration steps they are following are meant for Flutter and not for iOS (only).

Guide to remove dependencies (as suggested by [ΞΫΛL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547601/%CE%9E%CE%AB%CE%9Bl)):
[removing dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn9Wx.png)

Comment: I don't even have this one lol

Comment: Thanks! That solved it for me! For others that might be looking for this, that is in Xcode → Projects → Runner → Package dependencies

Comment: @ΞΫΛL Hi! I can't seem to find package dependencies folder/file under my runner. Can you enlighten me on this matter?

Comment: Try this guide: ![removing dependencies](https://i.imgur.com/th57QAJ.png)

Comment: Plz include the "removing dependencies" link in the answer! One shouldn't have to read comments to get what one needs, since according to StackOverflow docs, comments can be cleared away at any time.

Comment: May God bless your soul man. It worked!!!!!! Thank youuuuu!!!

Comment: Yes, that worked.  However, my stupid iPad still doesn't receive the notifications. :(

Comment: thanks, that solved it for me. solution: Xcode → click Show the project navigator → click your Project → Package dependencies -> click - (minus).

Answer (score 36):

As Wouter Pol suggested, this error will most likely happen if you followed to many configuration guides and did some iOS-specific (non-Flutter) setup for Firebase.

##### I had to undo two changes:

#### 1 - remove added code from AppDelegate.swift

Here is how it should look like - no `import Firebase` and no `FirebaseApp.configure()`

[image: appdelegate.swift for firebase push notifications with flutter]

#### 2 - No package dependencies

I added the Firebase package before, but I don't need it when I already configured Flutter with appropriate packages.
Here is how `Runner > Swift Packages` should look like:

[image: Runner > Swift Packages - no dependencies for Firebase notifications with flutter]

Comment: Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use M1 try this

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using a M1-cpu. I've tried it nonetheless but, as one might have expected, it did nothing to resolve the issue.