# Redefinition of module 'Firebase'

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate Firebase into my app, but as soon as I'm building it after I thought I finished my install I get:

```
Redefinition of module 'Firebase'
```

as well as

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftOverlayShims'
```

which I have no idea what that means but I'm assuming its a result of the first.

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'app' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  # Pods for app

end
```

So I don't think theres anything conflicting there.  I saw a solution that told me to go into my Header Search Path and see if my project had multiple Firebase directories, but I have no custom paths, so that wasn't it.  Any insight?

EDIT: Here is the exact display from my errors
[image]

Uncommenting the platform line in my podfile and changing it to iOS 10.0 did get rid of the error saying "Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'" So we have made some progress.

Here is the path when selecting "previously defined here"

[image]

From what I can tell, it is only giving me one location.  Selecting the redefinition error just gives me the relative path of module.modulemap , so I am assuming that is referring to the same thing.  I am also getting multiple warnings like this

```
Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Files build phase: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-elgcucdextsnzqbtlznbqeulbfks/SourcePackages/artifacts/Firebase/FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseAnalytics.framework
```

as well as a couple other frameworks in the ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator directory, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: So, You have already existing project, or it fails when You just create a new project, add 'Firebase/Auth' and run pod install?

Comment: It was an existing project.

Comment: Well, You can try first with `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`. Make some backup. Do this while Xcode is closed completely. Clean derived data, and see if it works.

Comment: Please remove the answer and describe what errors show up. Likely more context about SwiftOverlayShims is needed.

Comment: @Whirlwind that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I am getting 3 Errors: 1) Redefinition of module 'Firebase' -- I have it referenced in my code twice, once in AppDelegate, and once in the file I'm trying to use Firebase in.  It says it is referenced in the Firebase module as well

Comment: 2) @PaulBeusterien  Could not build Objective-C module 'SwiftOverlayShims' -- no idea what this is, all I did was try and install firebase so I don't know what this is even for.   in the error it says this is a result of the first -- redefinition of module 'Firebase'

Comment: @PaulBeusterien 3) Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' -- assuming this is also a result of the first, from it being redefined

Comment: Does the redefinition error message show where the previous definition was?

Comment: It says it is in module.modulemap which just says module Firebase { export * header "Firebase.h" @PaulBeusterien

Comment: And where is the redefinition?

Comment: It is currently throwing an error on every single .swift file actually.  I only have "import Firebase" in AppDelegate and in the file I'm actually trying to use it in.  So I'm not sure why I would be getting errors on things that are seemingly irrelevant. @PaulBeusterien

Comment: A redefinition error message should give two locations? Another issue is that Firebase now require iOS 10 so there should be something like `platform :ios, '10.0'` in the Podfile.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Edited my original question to give some more context.  But as far as i can tell it's only giving me one location.

Comment: Sharing a reproducible example in GitHub repo or other place may help others to help you. Otherwise, I suggest learning more about the Xcode error message detail window.

Comment: @JacobF Were you able to solve this, I am also facing this issue after upgrading the pods.

Comment: @BharatLalwani Honestly I can't remember, sorry

Answer (score 0):

so in my situation, this was not a flutter issue see -> [Flutter on iOS: redefinition of module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760326/flutter-on-ios-redefinition-of-module-firebase).
In my edge case scenario, I was cloning a repo and using the 'open in xcode' feature. Once opening the project , Xcode ran through the various setup and installation process of the project. What happened was it began installing both PODS and SWIFT PACKAGE MANAGER dependencies. For some reason it was installing firebase TWICE. Once in pods and second in package manager.

I recommend you use the package manager.